# RelativeSource Binding Tooltip to UserControl DependencyProperty Error

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I have a custom usercontrol that does a little animation on a DispatcherTimer tick, as well as update a DependencyProperty of that usercontrol :

```
public partial class EggCounter : UserControl
{
  DispatcherTimer eggTimer;

  public EggCounter()
  {
     // Required to initialize variables
     InitializeComponent();

     eggTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
     eggTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
     eggTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(eggTimer_Tick);
     eggTimer.Start();

     Eggs = 0;
  }

  void eggTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Eggs += 4;
     Pop.Begin();
     mePop.Play();
  }

  private void mePop_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     mePop.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The <see cref="Eggs" /> dependency property's name.
  /// </summary>
  public const string EggsPropertyName = "Eggs";
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="Eggs" />
  /// property. This is a dependency property.
  /// </summary>
  public int Eggs
  {
     get
     {
        return (int)GetValue(EggsProperty);
     }
     set
     {
        SetValue(EggsProperty, value);
     }
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Identifies the <see cref="Eggs" /> dependency property.
  /// </summary>
  public static readonly DependencyProperty EggsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(EggsPropertyName, typeof(int), typeof(EggCounter), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

The XAML for this code is irrelevant. Then, I place this control on my MainPage, like this :

```
<my:EggCounter ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Eggs, StringFormat='{} Our chickens have laid {0} eggs since you have been here.'}"/>
```

The page loads fine, but as soon as the timer fires, I get this error :

```
"The given key was not present in the dictionary."
```

in the Eggs property's setter in my usercontrol, i.e. on this line :

```
SetValue(EggsProperty, value);
```

I've also tried an ElementBinding on the control, but get the same error. Am I doing something wrong with the dependency property?

Comment: Your code contains `UIPropertyMetaData`.  Silverlight does not have this class, are you sure you meant to use the Silverlight tag or should you be using the WPF tag instead?

Comment: That was it. Used a WPF DP code snippet. Changing it to PropertyMetaData fixed the issue. If you make it an Answer, you'll get the booty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains `UIPropertyMetaData`. Silverlight does not have this class it uses just `PropertyMetaData` instead.

Having said that the failure mode you describe seems to indicate that your code compiles, I don't understand how even got that far.

Answer (score 0):

If use your code I don't get the error.

But I didn't had the lines

```
Pop.Begin();
mePop.Play();
```

in the TimerCallback. So propably you should seek the error in these two methods..